# Adding controls dynamically in mvc3 using Editortemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my program I am trying to add extra controls dynamically on button click.Is it possible by using EditorTemplates?
This is my EditorTemplates

```
@model chPayroll.Models.HREducation.HRInfo
      @{
          var list = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["PassedDivision"];
          var list1 = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["Country"];
        }
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.StaffId)
      <tr>
      <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, list1, "-select-")</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Board)</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Level)</td>
      <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.PassedYr)</td>
      <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.PassedDivision,list,"-selected-")</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="file"></td>
     </tr>
```

Now I want to add all controls dynamically on button click.
I am calling listeditor from the view.

```
@model chPayroll.Models.HREducation.HRInfo

<div align="left">
<fieldset style="left:0px">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Addcontrols", "HREduInformation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table >
        <tr>
        <th >Country</th>
        <th>Board</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Passed Year</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>certificate</th>
   </tr>

        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.listInfoeditor)

    </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Add New" id="savechanges" />
}
</fieldset>
</div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax to grab the rendered control Html.

[Editing a variable length list](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)

You can also go one step further and avoid the ajax call by using an already rendered template on the client side